# How to get the ID of images which are stored in smart phone's library

Tags: android

from the beginning I use

```
Drawable pic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android);
```

to get the drawable object while R.drawable.android means the ID of the picture I put in drawable folder.
However, I would like to get also the drawable object of the images which are stored in library.

do you have any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean by stored in library mean some where in SD card, then use

```
Drawable pic = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
```

or to get from stream

```
 Drawable pic = Drawable.createFromStream(is, srcName)
```